# How to change permissions on folders, but not files?

Tags: linux, permissions, mac-osx, chmod, recursive

Is there a concise linux command (that will work on OSX) to change permissions on folders and all of their contents, but leave files in the current directory untouched?  For example:

> /parent/folder1        <-change permissions
>   /parent/folder2        <-change permissions
>   /parent/folder3        <-change permissions
>   /parent/folder3/file1  <-change permissions
>   /parent/folder3/file2  <-change permissions
>   /parent/file1          <-do not change permissions
>   /parent/file2          <-do not change permissions

Answer (score 8):

You would need to run 2 commands I believe.  This is one way to do it:

```
# find . -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs chmod 700
# find . -mindepth 2 | xargs chmod 700
```

The first does directories at the current directory level and deeper.  The second does all files and directories deeper than the current directory.

Comment: Be careful with xargs, as it will most likely fail whenever the files/folders have spaces in their names. (it's possible to solve this passing some parameters to xargs... but is it really worth the trouble? It's easier to find -exec)

Comment: What Denilson said. Especially on macs, many files have spaces in them.

Answer (score 4):

This will change the permissions of every directory in the current directory and all files and folders within them, I think that's what you want but be careful because of the recursion...

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec chmod -R 700 {} \;
```

Comment: This wont change permissions on files in those directories.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `find` for this or maybe, with a loop, `for`:

```
for directory in parent/*; do if [ -d $directory ]; then chmod -R 700 $directory; fi ;done
```

Comment: That only handles the directories. He wants to do files and directories if they are deeper than the PWD.

Comment: Please note that chmod with -R flag, change permission in all directories and content recursively.

Comment: Missed that, my mistake.

Comment: `boucle, n 1: a fabric of uneven yarn that has an uneven knobby effect` - Huh?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: it seems that you don't like it :\

Comment: No, I just don't know how the word applies in this context or what its other meanings might be. Please enlighten me. Is it an idiom, slang, something else?

Comment: Don't worry man, keep the good sentences :)  and be sure that i did not understand the hole of your expression

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: Found it: "boucle" == "loop"

Comment: oups, i did not make attention to that, "boucle" mean a loop in french :\, i really was confused.

Answer (score 1):

There is one trivial case where `chmod` can do this on its own. If you set mode `+X` (note, capital, not lowercase), it will only apply to directories. This is commonly used for cases where you want to make all files in a directory tree group or world readable. You would do something like this:

```
chmod a+rX somedir
```

This will add read and execute permission to `somedir` and all directories beneath it, but just read permission to regular files beneath it. There unfortunately is no corresponding mode for read/write permissions, though.

Comment: Nice. I didnt know about the X option. OP wanted to chmon on files in lower directories, this doesnt do that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
find  . -type d -mindepth 1 -print -exec chmod 755 {}/* \;
```

Find every subdirectory of the current directory (-type d and -mindepth 1), and run chmod for all files in each directory found.

`{}` refers to the directory find is evaluating, and `/*` tells chmod to operate on just the files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one-liner for the general case:

```
find /parent -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -R 700
```

The `-print0` and `-0` arguments use NUL instead of newline as a record separator, so this is safe for filenames with spaces, newlines, and so on. And unlike `-exec`, it batches filenames into fewer invocations of `chmod`.

Bonus:

In cases where you know you don't have hidden directories at the top level of `/parent` (like `/parent/.foo`) it's even easier:

```
chmod -R 700 /parent/*/
```